# How to display columns which are not included in group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to display columns which are not included in group by clause?

```
select  user_id,DecryptString(first_name) as first_name, DecryptString(last_name) as last_name, DecryptString(middle_name) as middle_name,count(*)
from mamt
where middle_name<>'9ZnIFajWgaw='
  group by first_name,middle_name,last_name having count(*) >1;
```

here in teh above query,user_id is not in group by clause.but i want it to get displayed.
how can it be done?

Comment: You need to include user_id in the group_by since you are using an aggregate function (Count).

Comment: Add it to the `GROUP BY` clause, unless there are mutiple `user_id` for each grouped `first_name,middle_name,last_name`. In this case which `use_id` to display for each grouped `first_name,middle_name,last_name `? And how it can be multiple userids for each `first_name,middle_name,last_name`??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, hmm yeah..ok..i dont want that count.select  user_id,DecryptString(first_name) as first_name, DecryptString(last_name) as last_name, DecryptString(middle_name) as middle_name,count(*)
from mamt
where middle_name<>'9ZnIFajWgaw='
  group by first_name,middle_name,last_name; so now how to include user_id in the query?

Comment: Hi All, I want to get the user_id's of all the rows along with their names who have the same firstname,lastname and middlename.

Comment: Hi daniel,am using Toad,oracle 10g

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this:

```
select *
from (
select user_id, 
       DecryptString(first_name),
       DecryptString(middle_name),
       DecryptString(last_name), 
       count(*) over (partition by first_name,  middle_name, last_name) cn
from mamt
where middle_name<>'9ZnIFajWgaw=')
where cn > 1;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cf7c/7)

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
select  user_id, DecryptString(a.first_name),DecryptString(a.last_name), DecryptString(a.middle_name)
from mamt
inner join
(
select first_name, last_name,middle_name,count(*) as c
from mamt
where middle_name<>'9ZnIFajWgaw='
group by first_name,middle_name,last_name having count(*) >1
) a on a.first_name = mamt.first_name AND a.last_name = mamt.last_name AND a.middle_name = mamtmiddle_name
```